# Split a string at \n char but of a max of n character

Tags: javascript, string, split

in javascript I need to split a string of an unknown length in substrings of max 320 char but that trying to cut always after the last occurrence of `\n` to make every string "user friendly" - every string will be a facebook message..

Example, from:

> Ecco il tuo carrello:
>  • Frittata di spinaci dell'artusi
>  •
>   Frittata di spinaci dell'artusi
>  • Frittata di spinaci dell'artusi
>  •
>   Frittata di spinaci dell'artusi
>  • Frittata di spinaci dell'artusi
>  •
>   Frittata di spinaci dell'artusi
>  • Frittata di spinaci dell'artusi
>  •
>   Frittata di spinaci dell'artusi
>  • Frittata di spinaci dell'artusi
>  •
>   Frittata di spinaci dell'artusi
>  • Frittata di spinaci dell'artusi
>  •
>   Frittata di spinaci dell'artusi
>  • Frittata di spinaci dell'artusi
>  •
>   Frittata di spinaci dell'artusi
>  • Frittata di spinaci dell'artusi

to:

> Ecco il tuo carrello:
>  • Frittata di spinaci dell'artusi
>  • Frittata di
>   spinaci dell'artusi
>  • Frittata di spinaci dell'artusi
>  • Frittata di
>   spinaci dell'artusi
>  • Frittata di spinaci dell'artusi
>  • Frittata di
>   spinaci dell'artusi
>  • Frittata di spinaci dell'artusi
>  • Frittata di
>   spinaci dell'artusi

and

> • Frittata di spinaci dell'artusi
>  • Frittata di spinaci dell'artusi
>  •
>   Frittata di spinaci dell'artusi
>  • Frittata di spinaci dell'artusi
>  •
>   Frittata di spinaci dell'artusi
>  • Frittata di spinaci dell'artusi

Comment: Could you give an example of the input and the wanted output?

Comment: And what do you expect to happen if the substring first occurrence of `\n` happens after 320 chars?

Comment: I think I'll split at the nearest space available

Comment: I haven't written anything yet, I think it's more a conceptual idea that I need

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My approach would be like this.

- Get all lines into an array. (`lines`)
- Add each line one after the other in another array (`reduced`) at index 0 up until if the next line is added the total length exceeds 320 characters.
- Once the string at index 0 reaches to the limit to accept no more lines move on to index 1 and continue the same way.

```js
var text = "Ecco il tuo carrello:\n• Frittata di spinaci dell'artusi\n• Frittata di spinaci dell'artusi\n• Frittata di spinaci dell'artusi\n• Frittata di spinaci dell'artusi\n• Frittata di spinaci dell'artusi\n• Frittata di spinaci dell'artusi\n• Frittata di spinaci dell'artusi\n• Frittata di spinaci dell'artusi\n• Frittata di spinaci dell'artusi\n• Frittata di spinaci dell'artusi\n• Frittata di spinaci dell'artusi\n• Frittata di spinaci dell'artusi\n• Frittata di spinaci dell'artusi\n• Frittata di spinaci dell'artusi\n• Frittata di spinaci dell'artusi",
   lines = text.split("\n"),
       i = 0,
 reduced = lines.reduce((p,c) => { p[i].length + c.length <= 320 ? p[i]+= c + "\n"
                                                                 : p[++i] = c + "\n";
                                   return p;},[""]);
console.log(reduced);
console.log(reduced[0].length);
console.log(reduced[1].length);
```