# Split single line string into multiline string in JavaScript/p5.js

Tags: javascript, regex, string, p5.js, template-literals

I have a .csv file that I'm calling in JavaScript through a p5.js sketch. One of the fields contains sentences that range from 103 char to 328 char. My script calls the data and displays in randomly on the canvas. Because some of the sentences are very long, they aren't fitting on the canvas properly, so I'd like to split them into 2- or 3-line strings.

I've read up on [Template Literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) and [RegExp](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) in the JavaScript documentation, but all of the examples use string variables written out as a variable. So, for example, something like this in the case of my data:

```
var myString = `We can lift up people and places who've been left out, 
        from our inner cities to Appalachia,  
        in every manufacturing town hollowed out when the factory closed, 
        every community scarred by substance abuse, 
        every home where a child goes to bed hungry.`
```

That `Template Literal` would print to the canvas as a multiline object. But what I need to do is have JavaScript create a multiline object from the statements array in my data.

I have a `constructor` and a `prototype` that format the color, size, x/y placement, and motion of the sentences.

```
// Function to align statements, categories, and polarity
function Statement(category, polarity, statement) {
  this.category = category;
  this.statement = statement;
  this.polarity = polarity;
  this.x = random(width/2);
  this.y = random(height);
  this.dx = random(-speed, speed);
  this.dy = random(-speed, speed);
}
// Attach pseudo-class methods to prototype;
// Maps polarity to color and x,y to random placement on canvas
Statement.prototype.display = function() {
  this.x += this.dx;
  this.y += this.dy;
  if(this.x > width+10){
    this.x = -10
  }
  if(this.y > height+10) {
    this.y = -10
  }
  if(this.polarity == -1){
    fill(205, 38, 38);
  }
  else if(this.polarity == 1){
    fill(0, 145, 205);
  }
  else{
    fill(148, 0, 211);
  }
  textSize(14);
  text(this.statement, this.x, this.y);
}
```

So I suppose what I'm wondering is whether I need to create a `RegExp`, like `String.split("[\\r\\n]+")` and add `\r\n` into the data, and if so, where would I put it in my script. I tried in in the `Statement.display.prototype`, but it just seemed to break the whole script as the statements wouldn't load.

**EDIT:** I am adding this edit with some trepidation, as I got nailed for not producing a [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example, with "minimal" being the part I got nailed on. That said, here is the top part of my code.

```
var clContext;
var speed = 0.8;
var statements = [];
var category = [];
var canvas;



      //load the table of Clinton's words and frequencies
function preload() {
        clContext = loadTable("cl_context_rev.csv", "header");
      }

function setup() {
  canvas = createCanvas(680, 420);
  canvas.mousePressed(inWidth);
  background(51);
  // Calling noStroke once here to avoid unecessary repeated function calls
  noStroke();
  // iterate over the table rows
  for (var i = 0; i < clContext.getRowCount(); i++) {
    var category = clContext.get(i, "category");
    var statement = clContext.get(i, "statement");
    var polarity = clContext.get(i, "polarity");
    statements[i] = new Statement(category, polarity, statement);
  }
}

function draw() {
  if (mouseIsPressed) {
    background(51);
    for (var i = 0; i < statements.length; i++) {
      statements[i].display();
    }
  }
}
```

I've added that only to provide context for the data type I'm trying to split. There seems to be two points at which I could do the split: the `statement` array created in setup, or the `statements` array from the constructor. Meaning that if I go into my data file and add `\n` where I want to split, which is easy enough as there are only 20 statements, how and where is it best to construct a `RegExp` that will split those lines?

Comment: You can do it by defining a maximum length and then by reducing your string by splitting it at the end of the last word within your length limit into an array item. I had done a similar job in this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37361878/split-a-string-at-n-char-but-of-a-max-of-n-character/37366744#37366744

Comment: Thanks, @Redu, but that, unfortunately, didn't do it either. I tried adapting it with my var names and every time I tried to run it, with various configs, I got a `statement.split is not a function` error. I'm not sure, but it could be a p5.js problem. I had tried other `split` methods that I had run across and always got that error. I'll try creating an `issue` in the GitHub repo for p5.js, but they are not the fastest responders.

Comment: `statement.split is not a function` is a TypeError and means statement is not string type at all. Have you checked by doing `typeof statement`?

Comment: Yes, @Redu, I checked and it is string type.

Comment: Well this is unusual. Do you see `function split() { [native code] }` when you do like `console.log(String.prototype.split())` in your application..?

Comment: When I do that, the console shows just `[" "]`. p5.js has a `split()` and `splitTokens()`, with the syntax for both being `splitTokens(value,delim)`, so I've tried using that on the `statement` variable, using different delimiters, e.g., <br>, \r\n. None of my attempts have been successful.

Someone on the Processing/p5 form wrote a function to split the sentences, and when it run it with `console.log()`, the console SHOWS that the statements have been split, but they do not appear that way on my sketch display. Grrr....

Comment: Sorry my bad... the right thing to check was `console.log(String.prototype.split)`

Answer (score 1):

I dunno if I understand exactly that you want, but you can use this to get an array from template

```js
var myString = `We can lift up people and places who've been left out, 
        from our inner cities to Appalachia,  
        in every manufacturing town hollowed out when the factory closed, 
        every community scarred by substance abuse, 
        every home where a child goes to bed hungry.`
        
var array = myString.replace(/,/gi, "").split("\n").map(x => x.trim());

console.log(array);
```

Basically I removed all the commas of your example with `replace(/,/gi, "")`, then split for `\n`, and finally trim it.

Comment: Thanks@AralRoca, but not exactly apropos. My statements are in rows of a data file, with the variable name `statement`. I have called the statements into an array in `setup()`. Also, when I used a modified version of your code: `var array = statements.split("\n").map(x => x.trim());`, I got `Uncaught TypeError: statements.split is not a function`. Perhaps I should have put more of my script, and I can do that, but I got nailed in a previous question for not making a [MINIMAL, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), minimal being the specific I got nailed on.

Comment: Because `split` prototype is only for  `strings`. If you have statements with statement variable, maybe you can try this:

`const templateToArray = (s) => s.replace(/,/gi, "").split("\n").map(x => x.trim());`

and then:

`const array = statements.map( s => templateToArray(s.statement));`

And finally you can flatten, for example, using lodash:

`const flattenArray = _.flattenDeep(array);`

Comment: Thanks @AralRoca, but I think that because `const` are declared before any function, it's not working. The second `const` throws a `cannot map to undeclared` error. My `statement` variable is actually declared in `setup()`, since I have to first use `preload = loadTable()` to bring in the data. Your example is based on the dummy variable that I typed out to reference Template Literals. That's not actually what my data looks like, which are just numerous rows of sentences in a .csv file. You can see all of this in my **Edit:** with the top part of my code.

Comment: well, you need to declare first the variable `statements` hehe. And sorry, because I think that finally I don't understand that you want

Comment: .@AralRoca The variable `var statements = []` is declared at the very top of my script (he he), but it wasn't included in my post, as I keep getting hammered for either posting TOO MUCH of my script or NOT ENOUGH! I know about minimal, complete, verifiable examples, but it's just ridiculous to try to satisfy everyone because everyone seems to have a different idea about what that means, and they've ALL let me know how I've failed!

Answer (score 0):

I think the other answer overthinks it a bit.

P5.js already has a handy `split()` function that you should be using. You can read about it in the reference [here](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/split).

But basically, all you really need to do is change your `statement` variable into an array instead of a single string value.

```
function Statement(category, polarity, statement) {
  this.statement = split(statement, "//");
  //rest of your code
```

This code assumes that you've inserted a `//` into your `.csv` file wherever you want a line break. You could use any delimiter you want though.

You would then have to modify your `display()` function to use the `statement` variable as an array instead of a single value. How you do that is up to you, but the basic syntax would look like this:

```
text(this.statement[0], this.x, this.y);
text(this.statement[1], this.x, this.y+25);
```

Comment: Weird. Had tried something similar with p5's `splitTokens()` and it didn't work, but this did. By `display()` function, I assume you mean the `Statement.prototype.display = function()`, since that's where I have `text(this.statement, this.x, this.y)`. That leaves me with a question. Apparently, I also have to change `statements[i] = new Statement(polarity, statement);` under `setup()`, & `for (var i = 0; i < statements.length; i++) { statements[i].display();}` under `draw()`, as I get a `Cannot read property 'display' of undefined` error. But shouldn't `statements[i]` cover all instances?

Comment: @LesleyLathrop It's really hard to talk about code in comments, and comments aren't really designed for extended discussion. I suggest creating a new post with your updated code (preferably as a [mcve]) and your new questions, and we'll go from there.

Comment: I've added another edit above with the mostly complete revised code. I am NOT going to post a new question and have someone knock me for duplicating a question that's already been asked. And, btw, you no longer need to remind me about minimal, complete, verifiable examples. I get it, although, as a writer, I have to say that "minimal" and "complete" are contradictory terms. And I get nailed when I don't post ENOUGH code, and you nail me for posting TOO MUCH.

Comment: @LesleyLathrop I wasn't reminding you of anything. StackOverflow automatically expands `[mcve]` into [mcve], so it happened automatically. I'm not sure why you're reacting with so much hostility, but I'll be happy to help if you post your follow-up question into its own post. It gets really confusing to later readers if we keep editing our questions and answers. If you don't want to do that, that's okay, but then I'll wish you good luck and move on. There are plenty of questions I can be answering without being yelled at by the people I'm trying to help.

Comment: .@KevinWorkman, I was absolutely not yelling at you or anyone, and there was no hostile intent in my comment. I was merely expressing frustration that, regardless of how little or how much code I post, someone inevitably takes issue with it and tells me about posting [mcve]. I apologize if you thought I was directing any animus at you, because I was not. Per your request, I have [posted a new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37830451/getting-typeerror-when-trying-to-call-multiline-string-in-p5-js), and I would very much appreciate any help you could offer. Thanks!